# Scalar field components in unitarity gauge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, higgs, symmetry-breaking

The [Wikipedia article on Unitarity gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_gauge) says - "In this gauge, the scalar fields responsible for the Higgs mechanism are transformed into a basis in which their Goldstone boson components are set to zero."

Are these components equal to zero at each point in space-time or only on average over space-time?

Answer (score 0):

It's at each point, but this is all a discussion of specifically the ground state$^\dagger$. As per Sec. 4.3.4 [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnChalker/theory/lecture-notes.pdf), the ground state has a spacetime-constant value for the scalar multiplet, called its vacuum expectation value. If we work in a basis of eigenvectors of the unbroken symmetry's Lie algebra's generators, the VEV has zero-valued components for the Goldstone bosons; see also Sec. 4.3.3. What we've done here, in fact, is to absorb these bosons' degrees of freedom into vector fields, viz. Sec. 4.4.2, so the ground state minimizes a potential that can be written only in terms of the massive modes.

$^\dagger$ The focus on this as a important special case is explained on the last page of Sec. 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

These components equal zero at each point in space-time; this is not an average statement. They have been redefined, at each point of spacetime, through a (local) gauge transformation, into the massive ex-gauge-fields so there is hardly any remnant of them, beyond the structure of the theory. [Here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism#Spontaneous_breaking_of_a_local_gauge_symmetry) is the toy prototype of that gauge transformation, from the horse's mouth!

Unfortunately (perhaps relatedly?) this gauge is not the friendliest for calculations, and, in a potentially paradoxical way, features of these components all but reemerge in special high-energy amplitudes involving longitudinal degrees of freedom of the gauge fields.

This is dubbed the *Equivalence Theorem* ([Peskin (2017), Sec 5](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/17000/slac-pub-17142.pdf) ),   the duck quacking from inside the wolf's belly in [Peter and the Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_and_the_Wolf), but this outranges the scope of your question.

Comment: What gauge transformation is used to zero these goldstone components and give to scalar field a non-zero positive expectation value?

Comment: You upended the logic, completely! The Engler-Brout-Higgs gauge transformation to the unitarity gauge is designed to do just that: to zero out the Goldstone components, by definition. It has ***nothing*** to do with the non vanishing v.e.v., causally. That v.e.v. is a requirement for SSB, which, in turn, is a requirement for the Higgs mechanism that zeroes out the goldstons.

Comment: And? I expected to see some transformation acting on φ, to align the field in $φ^0$ direction. Maybe some kind of rotation matrix.

Comment: In the toy Abelian example, Kibble demonstrates how a U(1) (O(2), really) rotation aligns the $(\varphi_1,\varphi_2)$ field to $(\varphi_1,0)$. The non-Abelian generalization of this, a weak-isospin/hypercharge rotation matrix,  eliminates 3 instead of 1 Goldstone bosons!

Comment: Yes. i meant this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle

Comment: You've flipped to another chapter, logically! The weak mixing angle tells you how the weak isospin and hypercharge mix in their zero-charge sector; it is a conceptually irrelevant wrinkle. First convince yourself that the charged Goldstone bosons disappear and make the charged Ws massive, and only then redefine the fields to see that a particular combination of B and W0 ate the neutral goldston. PS: WP is not a tutorial: go to your textbook or a decent curse to be introduced to the concepts.

Comment: I meant to use angle between goldstone component and preferred direction to align. And rotating both through this rotation matrix

Comment: Read "course" for "curse" above. The spell-checker demon is in a mood...

Comment: Indeed, that's the point: The O(4) vector of the 4 Higgs components rotates to the surviving *h* component zeroing the 3 Goldstone components by an isorotation involving 3 angles.

Comment: I probably phrased it wrong at first, but $φ^0$ component is $v + h$ where v is constant v.e.v and h is fluctuations of higgs field. And this component is non-zero and positive after gauge-fixing.

Comment: Yes, all true. This is the only degree of freedom that is not entering in the Higgs mechanism in a significant way...

Comment: By the way, your second comment is not useful here, what we talking here is not SSB but gauge-fixing, which explicitly breaks the symmetry

Comment: ? Nobody fixed any gauge here. One inspects how different equivalent gauges look, and, specifically, peculiar properties of the unitarity gauge...

Comment: My talk about aligning scalar field into preferred direction by rotation matrices is not counting?

Comment: I don't understand you. A special rotation takes you to that gauge; another one to another gauge. The physics stays the same.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer

Comment: Is the point clear? At each point in spacetime, the goldston-as-angle isorotation eliminates all goldstons.